# Use FastAPI to interact with async loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi

I am running coroutines of 'workers' whose job it is to wait 5s, get values from an asyncio.Queue() and print them out continually.

```
q = asyncio.Queue()

def worker():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        i = await q.get()
        print(i)
        q.task_done()

async def main(q):
    workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker()) for n in range(10)]
    await asyncio.gather(*workers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I would like to be able to interact with the queue through http requests using FastAPI. For example POST requests that would 'put' items in the queue for the workers to print.

I'm unsure how I can run the coroutines of the workers concurrently with FastAPI to achieve this effect. Uvicorn has its own event loop I believe and my attempts to use asyncio methods have been unsuccessful.

The router would look something like this I think.

```
@app.post("/")
async def put_queue(data:str):
    return q.put(data)
```

And I'm hoping there's something that would have an effect like this:

```
await asyncio.gather(main(),{FastApi() app run})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option would be to add a task that wraps your main coroutine in [a on startup event](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/)

```py
import asyncio
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    asyncio.create_task(main())
```

This would schedule your main coroutine before the app has been fully started.

Important here is that you don't await the created task as it would basically block startup_event forever

Comment: Do you know if there are any drawbacks to this? I am wondering which thread manages this process. Say if there was some blocking code inside main(), do you know if would that slow down my entire server?

Comment: @rID133 it would absolutely slow down your entire server, as it is using the same event-loop that the server is using to respond to requests. The fast-api documentation explains how to run [background tasks within the event loop](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/#caveat) but points out running it as its own process with something like Celery is a better idea